# Aligning columns in nested tables

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to figure out why these Bootstrap tables don't align. All three in the image below are within one parent table. These are the child tables:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed no-bottom-pad" style="width:100%;">
```

This is the parent:

```
<table class="table borderless table-condensed">
```

[image]

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0f561kef/)

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: @zer00ne have added fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems there.

When you build a `table` inside a `table`, that insider table works independent from the parent table, so that's why the columns don't align.

A solution here is to have one single `<thead>` that will control all the other `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Also when you want a `<td>` to have the width of multiple columns you add `colspan="x"` this case x = 3 because you have 3 columns.
Example:

```
<tr class="text-danger">
    <td colspan="3">1 laptop was not added because there were no unique identifiers (hostname, asset tag or serial).</td>
</tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0f561kef/3/

P.S. please ident your code correctly, that was a nightmare to understand where the tags start and close and its childs/parents :/

Comment: Sorry - copied and pasted straight out of a PHP file. Looks fine in Atom, but I guess not in jsfiddle!

Answer (score 5):

Use one table and multiple `<tbody>`ies. The long cells are better off if you use `colspan='3'`. Basically, wherever you want another table, use a `<tbody>` instead. `<tbody>` was designed for sectioning a table. Btw, there can only be one`<thead>` and one `<tfoot>` per table only, which is the reason why the last two rows of `<th>` are not in a `<thead>`. Here's the <kbd>[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/dvrtnmmw/)</kbd>
The following example is a basic layout of what I suggest:

### EXAMPLE

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>tbody Sections</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>TH1A</th>
      <th>TH2A</th>
      <th>TH3A</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TD1A</td>
      <td>TD2A</td>
      <td>TD3A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TD4A</td>
      <td>TD5A</td>
      <td>TD6A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>TH1B</th>
      <th>TH2B</th>
      <th>TH3B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TD1B</td>
      <td>TD2B</td>
      <td>TD3B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
  <td colspan='3'>This is where info like missing laptops should go. Unfortunately, having more than one tfoot in a table is invalid.</td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou - had to give it to the other poster as she was first.

Comment: Actually, you accept the answer that helped the most, but I'm glad my answer helped regardless.

Comment: yh here doesn't matter how answers first. we all try to help you